# React Native Read User Email Without Prompting

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

If I install an app on Google Play I notice that it informs me about what permissions the app requires. Once it does it in the app it also prompts me. This is all very fine.

I would like to just read the Google or Apple account e-mail - without prompting the end user for an e-mail.

I don't want to use the email as an auth token, but prefill a "Subscribe to News Letter" field. The user can then toggle ON or OFF (or choose to add another email).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm getting the question right,
You need to get the primary email address of the currently signed in user, which can be used to pre-fill some kind of a form (eg. sign-up form)

**For Android**

Try the following react native wrapper library [react-native-account-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-account-manager)

Once you have setup using the instructions on the readme from the above link, use the following code to retrieve the list of signed in google accounts.

*Please note this could result in an empty list, if there are no google accounts associated with the device*

```
import AccountManager from 'react-native-account-manager';

AccountManager.getAccountsByType('accountName').then((accounts) => {
// console.log('available accounts', accounts);
let [firstAccount] = accounts;

AccountManager.getUserData(firstAccount, 'storedKey').then((storedData) => {
// console.log('stored data for storeKey', storedData);

AccountManager.setUserData(account, 'storedKey', JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"})).then(() => {
  // console.log('data successfully stored');
  })
});
})
```

**For iOS**

*Bad luck*

Apple does **NOT** expose the iPhone user’s details like their email address, password or credit card details to the app developer.

An alternative is to use the icloud token to create the user. You could use the [following guide to do it](https://medium.com/@skreutzb/ios-onboarding-without-signup-screens-cb7a76d01d6e)

For a wrapper on obtaining a iCloud token using react-native use [react-native-icloud-user-token](https://github.com/joshuakarjala/react-native-icloud-user-token)library

Kudos

Comment: I don't want to use the email as an auth token but would like to make it super easy to subscribe to a newsletter (which they can toggle ON or OFF).

Comment: If that is the case then you could only get the email from android to fill the subscription form. For iOS you need to prompt for the email address